# .NET Equivalant for INET_NTOA and INET_ATON

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Any C#/.Net equivalent methods, or managed code examples for INET_NTOA and INET_ATON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this forum thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/00a001af-e01d-4590-82c1-1f6142eb8c34

Answer (score 3):

The [`IPAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.ipaddress) class has static methods:

```
HostToNetworkOrder
NetworkToHostOrder
```

With various overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you're looking to parse a string representation of an IP Address, to an IPAddress object?

(That's my understanding of [this article](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) explaining INET_NTOA)

In that case ,it's `System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")`, and you can use the `.ToString()` off an IPAddress to get the string rep back out.

Answer (score 0):

To make NTOA compatible with MySQL i had to do a Endian conversion

```
byte[] ip = BitConverter.GetBytes(ipInt);
Array.Reverse(ip);

IPAddress = new IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(ip,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997836/are-there-any-net-framework-method-that-does-inet-aton):

```
string s = "174.36.207.186";

uint i = s.Split('.')
          .Select(uint.Parse)
          .Aggregate((a, b) => a * 256 + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to `INET_ATON` and `INET_NTOA` in `MySQL`

```cs
public static uint INetA2N(string ip)
{
    try
    {
        uint result = ip.Split('.')
                        .Select(uint.Parse)
                        .Aggregate((a, b) => a * 256 + b);
        return result;
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {

        return 0;
    }
}

public static string InetN2A(uint ipValue)
{
    if (ipValue > 4294967295 || ipValue < 0)
        return string.Empty;

    return ((ipValue & 0xFF000000) / 16777216).ToString() + "." +
           ((ipValue & 0x00FF0000) / 65536).ToString() + "." +
           ((ipValue & 0x0000FF00) / 256).ToString() + "." +
           (ipValue & 0x000000FF).ToString();
}
```