# Convert IP Address into int, (ie inet aton in c#)

Tags: c#, string, int, ip

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [.NET Equivalant for INET_NTOA and INET_ATON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887890/net-equivalant-for-inet-ntoa-and-inet-aton)
>   [How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)

How do I perform the same unix function inet_aton in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int ToInteger(int A, int B, int C, int D)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32((A* Math.Pow(256, 3)) + (B* Math.Pow(256, 2)) + (C* 256) + D);
}
```

or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx

you can extend your own IP class like I did.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [IPAddress.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) (or TryParse) methods of the IPAddress class.

An example would be:

```
static int IPStringToInt(string ipAddress)
{
    IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
    byte[] asBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();

    if(asBytes.Length != 4)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("IP Address must be an IPv4 address");
    }

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(asBytes, 0);
}
```

You will need to take into account the host and network order of the bytes, but there's several static methods on the IPAddress class for handling that.

Answer (score -1):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c) i think is the same question and it has an answer (enjoy)

Comment: This should be a vote to close.