# Are there any .NET Framework Method that does INET_ATON()

Tags: c#, inet-aton

That does this calculation below

```
address = '174.36.207.186'

( o1, o2, o3, o4 ) = address.split('.')

integer_ip =   ( 16777216 * o1 )
             + (    65536 * o2 )
             + (      256 * o3 )
             +              o4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an IPv4 address into a integer in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c)

Comment: Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/00a001af-e01d-4590-82c1-1f6142eb8c34)

Comment: i checked both place and did not find working solution. first of all it has to be int 64 not 32

Comment: `Int32` would not support addresses larger than `127.255.255.255`; however, `UInt32` would support the full IPv4 range. `Int64` would be overkill.

Comment: I think that the solution from @Douglas is far better than the duplicate signaled. Let this question and its answer open please

Comment: @Steve totally agree. those duplicates actually does not contain proper answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string s = "174.36.207.186";

uint i = s.Split('.')
          .Select(uint.Parse)
          .Aggregate((a, b) => a * 256 + b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the numbers into a byte array, then use `BitConverter.ToInt32` to put them together into an int:

```
byte[] parts = address.Split('.').Select(Byte.Parse).ToArray();
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(parts);
}
int ip = BitConverter.ToInt32(parts, 0);
```

Comment: `Int32` only supports addresses up to `127.255.255.255`.

Comment: @Douglas: Not at all. Addresses higher than that are represented as negative `int` values. You can cast the `int` it to `uint` if you like that better.

Comment: Fair point. I should have said that the intent is less clear with negative numbers. For example, any assumed ordering would be broken; `127.0.0.0 < 128.0.0.0` would evaluate as false using `Int32` representations.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the string to an IPAddress instance and then access the [Address Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.address.aspx):

```
long result = IPAddress.Parse("174.36.207.186").Address;
```

Note that this will yield a compiler warning (obsolete property), because it doesn't work with IPv6.

Comment: not returnign same value for example ip : 1.0.145.221 returns : 3717267457 while it should return : 16814557

Comment: Maybe you need [NetworkToHostOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k9k5fyd.aspx)?

Comment: how to use it ? i tried several combinations but does not accept ip as parameter